# using construct with CreateFileAsync(C#)

Tags: c#, uwp

So I'm trying to output some data to a `csv` file. I've got no issues with the code the first time it runs but it breaks if I don't close and reopen the program (because the file is still in use.)
I'm creating it with the following code.

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath));
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(outputFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file , content);
```

It was suggested I should be using the `using` construct but when I try it I get this error.

> CS1674    'StorageFile': type used in a using statement must be
> implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

There's obviously something I'm ignorant of but I don't know what.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *It was suggested I should be using the using construc* by who ? "using construct" is for use with `IDisposable` and `StorageFile` doesn't implement it

Comment: By someone on another forum site a while ago. Is there something else I can use to allow me to close the file after writing to it?

Comment: If you want to use the `using` pattern, then convert it to a .NET stream using [`WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-convert-between-dotnet-streams-and-winrt-streams)

Answer (score 0):

Your class must implement [IDisposable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)